# MySQL: Overlay modifications on original data while indexing on a field that itself has modifications

Tags: mysql, index, view, data-integrity

I have a MySQL table of original_data that is important for historical/auditing purposes and should not ever be changed. I want to be able to mark up these data with modifications, e.g. to correct errors in the original data entry, and view the overall composite dataset (changes overlaid on original data), without making any modifications to the table of original_data.

My fields are a mix of int, varchar, and datetime; nothing bizarre.

The system currently accomplishes this with the following:

> - A table *original_data* (which is never modified). This is indexed
>     on a datetime field.
> - A table *modifications*, which includes all fields that
>     original_data has. Each row in modifications references the primary
>     key of the row in original_data that is modified.
> - A view *mods_overlay* that joins original_data to modifications on
>     a key, displaying modified data (where it exists) in place of original
>     data. I'm using CASE WHEN statements to return fields from
>     modifications where they exists for a particular row, else return the
>     field from original_data.

So far, so good! The problem is, I have millions of rows, and one of the fields I need to modify is the datetime field on which original_data is indexed. As soon as my mods_overlay view overlays this datetime field, I can no longer efficiently select my data on a specific period of time; runtime for select statements increases from a few seconds to 30+ minutes. MySQL does not support indexing for views, nor does it support materialized views, either of which could help here.

One workaround: I could implement mods_overlay as a table that is pre-computed overnight, but then new modifications cannot be seen until the next day, and I'm not sure if this will be acceptable.

Are there other ways to solve this problem without making significant tooling changes?

Stated differently: is there a best practice in MySQL for providing a way to overlay a set of modifications on a set of original data (in a table that is never modified), while indexing on a field that can itself have modifications?

Comment: You could index the datetime field in the `modifications` table and do two queries - one witch WHERE for the original one and second for WHERE in the other one - that way both queries should be fast and you can just get few rows which you do not want because the "effective" datetime is not the one, but it should be quite easy to filter them out (just doing `orig.datetime = X AND (mod.datetime IS NULL OR mod.datetime = X)` in the first query should take care of it)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new approach to solve this problem, it may not be applicable to your case but worths a look I think.

Some new databases such as [`dolt`](https://github.com/dolthub/dolt) or [`noms`](https://github.com/attic-labs/noms) (that have a compatibility with mySQL in term of connector) are able to work like `git` actually letting you modify data while keeping the original in a previous `commit`.
The modified data is naturally indexed through the nominal index. There are requests to check what changed and so on.

The idea behind these databases is that data can dealt with as code source would be in `git`. So the data in tables can be tagged, and the whole database supports tags and branches as in source code controls.
Based on that, it is possible to tag the version that you consider to be your reference, alter your data just normally and then do requests with `SELECT somedata FROM mytable FOR COMMIT_HASH AS OF HASHOF("reference-tag")`, and of course the standard `SELECT somedata FROM mytable` to obtain the current state.

You can also see how data was modified through diff (dolt_diff_$TABLENAME) or history (dolt_history_$TABLENAME).

Comment: can  you elabrate your approach?

Answer (score 0):

Very few users use `VIEWs`.

The typical approach is to `ALTER` the table to make the desired schema changes.

`pt-online-schema-change` is the tool of choice if `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` is not available for the desired change.

Comment: terrible answer.. The question include the reasoning for using OVERLAY, and the writing doesn't strike me as consistent with someone who doesn't know about ALTER.